# php android apk parser doesn't show version code

Tags: java, php, xml, apk, server

i have been using php apk parser for my project, and when i wanna test it, its work good in [my server](http://nazriyab.com/apk/examples/ApkInfo.php) but it does not work good in [another one](http://miadstore.com/apk_parser3/examples/ApkInfo.php) and does not show version code,min SDK level and etc.
when i get xml string, version code has null value!
but it's work fine in another server and after trying lots still can't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

finally found it!
I am working on a 64-machine where -1 != 0xffffffff. Replacing -1 with 0xffffffff solves the problem.